# Upgrade version from Yii 2.0.12 to Yii 2.0.14 or higher

Tags: yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app

Currently, My project using version of Yii 2.0.12. But I want to use extension `yiisoft/yii-queue`. 
When I run command `composer require yiisoft/yii-queue` to install this extension, this throw message require to update Yii version to 2.0.14 to use `yiisoft/yii-queue`.

So, I run command `composer require "yiisoft/yii2:~2.0.14" --update-with-all-dependencies` to update Yii version, but met message of this command is:

```
  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: yiisoft/yii2[2.0.14, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: yiisoft/yii2[2.0.14.1, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: yiisoft/yii2[2.0.14.2, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: yiisoft/yii2[2.0.15, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: yiisoft/yii2[2.0.15.1, dev-master].
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 dev-master -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[dev-master].
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 ~2.0.14 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2, 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

And here is my composer.json

```
 {
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-authclient": "*",
        "zhelyabuzhsky/yii2-sitemap": "*",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel":"*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.1",
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.7",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^3.1",
        "trntv/probe": "^1.0",
        "philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar": "^3.9"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "php init --env=Development --overwrite=n"
    }
}
```

Anyone help me to upgrade yii version in this case, I tried to search many times and pages but not have solution for me :(

Thank you so much.

Comment: isnt it `--update-with-dependencies` rather than `--update-with-all-dependencies` ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam thanks, I was try this option but have same error with option ```--update-with-all-dependencies``` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your project name. According to your `composer.json` your project is `yiisoft/yii2`, which is not true. I have no idea how did you get this `composer.json`, [here is the official template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic) - your app structure and `composer.json` should look similar (alternatively you may try [advanced template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced)). After changing package name, this command should do the trick:

```
composer require yiisoft/yii2-queue --update-with-all-dependencies
```